# Multiplying inner products in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, quantum-states

Getting introduced to mixed states in QM, I have trouble with a proof. In particular there was a line where multiple quantum states $\Psi_i, \Psi_j$ and an arbitrary base $n$ in Hilbert space was multiplied in the following way

$$ \langle n | \Psi_i \rangle \langle \Psi_i | \Psi_j \rangle \langle \Psi_j | n \rangle, $$

and in the next step converted to

$$ \langle \Psi_i | \Psi_j \rangle \langle \Psi_j | n \rangle \langle n | \Psi_i \rangle. $$

I do not understand why one can just swap inner products

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I do not understand why one can just swap inner products

These inner products are just complex numbers and therefore commute with each other.

The analogous thing with 3D vectors (where the inner product is a real number) is unsurprising:

$$(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})(\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{d})=(\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{d})(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})$$